# Creating controlled R1 gates in Q#?

Tags: quantum-gate, programming, q#

I know how to create controlled versions of gates like X, Y, Z. For example, a controlled X gate would be implemented by writing

`(Controlled X)([control],target);`

However, I've tried numerous times to create a controlled R1 gate with no success, and there are no examples available on the Q# documentation or elsewhere on the web from what I've seen. As an example of what I've attempted, I've tried

`(Controlled R1)([control],theta,target);`

and get the following error:

`The shape of the given tuple does not match the argument type.`

From what I gather the issue is that an X gate does not require any additional parameters, whereas an angle needs to be specified for the R1 gate to be well defined.

To see the relevant documentation, please visit [R1 Operation, Q# Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.intrinsic.r1), and [Operations and Functions, Q# Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/quantum/techniques/operations-and-functions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the base operation takes several arguments, you need to enclose the corresponding arguments of the controlled version of the operation in parentheses to convert them into a single tuple. In your case, you need to call it as `(Controlled R1)([control], (theta, target));`.

This is covered in the "Controlled" section of [Q# type model documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/language/type-model#operation-and-function-types) with Rz gate used as an example. I wonder how to make this information more discoverable...

Comment: I was looking through the Operations and Functions section of the docs which is probably why I overlooked this. Just as a suggestion, it would probably be easier if they included examples of how to use these functors on the Microsoft.Quantum.Primitive gate pages. In any event, thanks for the help.